# How to pass quoted parameters to another program

Tags: string, bash, parameters, escaping, quotes

In a bash script, I need to pass a parameter to another program. The parameter has spaces in so must be quoted. Everything works fine in this simple case 1:

```
/bin/echo /some/command --param="abc def ghi"
```

*Output:*

```
/some/command --param=abc def ghi
```

The problem begins if I want to make the bash script more sophisticated, somehow the parameter value has changed in case 2 and 3:

```
FOO="ghi"
DEFAULTS="--param=\"abc def $FOO\""
/bin/echo /some/command $DEFAULTS

DEFAULTS='--param="abc def '$FOO'"'
/bin/echo /some/command $DEFAULTS
```

*Output:*

```
/some/command --param="abc def ghi"
/some/command --param="abc def ghi"
```

The double quotes surrounding `abc def ghi` are shown in 2 and 3, whereas they are not shown for 1.

This is better illustrated by having /some/command actually print what it receives as the first parameter. Here the whole string `"abc def ghi"` is received as the value of the `param` parameter:

```
perl -le'print $ARGV[0]' param="abc def ghi"
```

*Output (right):*

```
param=abc def ghi
```

But here only `"abc` is received, with one leading quote:

```
DEFAULTS='param="abc def ghi"'
perl -le'print $ARGV[0]' $DEFAULTS

DEFAULTS="param=\"abc def ghi\""
perl -le'print $ARGV[0]' $DEFAULTS
```

*Output (wrong):*

```
param="abc
param="abc
```

How do I use bash to dynamically construct a string like `param="abc def ghi"` and be able to pass it intact to another command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array; this is why they were introduced.

```
FOO="ghi"
# Contains one element, but not the literal quotes
DEFAULTS=(--param="abc def $FOO")
# command gets 1 argument, the single element of the array
/some/command "${DEFAULTS[@]}"

# Two elements
DEFAULTS=(--param="abc def $FOO" --other="foo bar")
# command gets 2 arguments
/some/command "${DEFAULTS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You just have to put the `$DEFAULTS` into double quotes so that bash doesn't do the word spliting.

```
DEFAULTS='param="ac def ghi"'
perl -le'print $ARGV[0]' "$DEFAULTS"
```

Output:

```
param="ac def ghi"
```

Comment: Although this does answer the question as asked, it doesn't scale to multiple parameters