# How to pass a quoted argument to another program in a bash script?

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing, quotes

rclone is a backup program I run from a bash script.
I want to pass in this parameter to rclone:

```
--exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**"
```

rclone needs those quotes.
Here is my failed attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd='rclone sync /home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1 /home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1 --exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**"'

printf "command: \n$cmd\n\n"
echo "$cmd"
#echo and printf output as expected:
#rclone sync /home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1 /home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1 --exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**"

#rclone with --exclude works as expected:
$(rclone sync /home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1 /home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1 --exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**")

#on these $cmd, rclone works but the --exclude is not excluding:
$cmd
$($cmd)
```

It's weird because the literal string output by echo "$cmd" works as expected.

```
$(rclone sync /home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1 /home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1 --exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**")
```

But the command $cmd does not work as expected.

```
$cmd
```

There are two similar questions that are NOT trying to pass in the quotes:

- [How to pass quoted arguments from variable to bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012991/how-to-pass-quoted-arguments-from-variable-to-bash-script)
- [How to pass quoted parameters to another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583458/how-to-pass-quoted-parameters-to-another-program)

Comment: Don't put the command in a variable. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Oh, and the two questions you linked both give valid answers to this.

Comment: did you try escaping the ". --exclude \"{secret1b,secret1c}/**\"

Comment: @abhishekphukan, making the quotes literal in that way completely changes the behavior from the original command (where they're syntactic). Moreover, the command that the OP is telling us works -- when they run the `echo` results as a shell command -- is a case where the quotes are syntactic (controlling how the shell divides argument lists) and not data (part of the individual `argv` elements passed to `rclone`).

Comment: @user2867994, you may **think** that you need to pass the quotes as literal data, but **YOU ARE WRONG**. If running the `echo "$cmd"` output works as expected when you copy-and-paste it back to a shell, then it's working with those quotes being parsed **as syntax**, not as data.

Comment: @user2867994, run `set -x` to tell the shell to log every command it runs, and compare the logs in that mode with the working command against those from your various attempts.

Comment: Alternately, if you want to display your working argument list **as data**, you can do the following: `printf '%s\n' rclone sync /home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1 /home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1 --exclude "{secret1b,secret1c}/**"` to emit each argument literally one-per-line. You'll see that the quotes aren't actually there in the literal argument list, because they're syntax, not literal shell data.

Comment: For the same reason, if you were writing your program in Python and using `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False)`, then the Python array for correct operation would be `cmd=['rclone', 'sync', '/home/wolfv/test_rclone_data/direc1', '/home/wolfv/test_rclone_backup/last_snapshot/direc1', '--exclude', '{secret1b,secret1c}/**']` -- note again that the only quotes here are *syntactic* ones, instructions to the language (in this example Python); not *literal* ones passed to `rclone`.

Comment: If you read [the `rclone` documentation](https://rclone.org/docs/), you'll note that the instructions to use quotes are in a section called "Quoting and the shell", which tells you to refer to your shell's rules and documentation for details. That's for a reason -- the quotes are there *for the shell's use*, not for `rclone`'s.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Getting rid of the double quotes worked: --exclude {secret1b,secret1c}/**   Thank you!   If you post it as answer I will accept it, otherwise I will post the answer in 24 hours.

Comment: @user2867994, that's really not a good answer, for all the reasons given in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Please leverage the solutions given there, or in the questions you linked; [this answer by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586295/14122) is particularly on-point.